# How to launch calendar application on windows through shellExecute

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Right now I am launching mail application through

`ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "mailto:", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

and then invoking the Calendar button.
Is there anyway I can launch the calendar independently through shellExecute?

Comment: mailto: opens the default mail program, the fact that the default in *your pc* also has a calendar is not a good assumption for other pcs.

Comment: I don't think you can run the Calendar App as a stand alone. It has to run within the App framework.